# I can not return a value for function in mysql

Tags: mysql, function

```
CREATE FUNCTION `new_function` ()
RETURNS bigint
BEGIN

set  @Ingredient:= (select Ingredient_cost_ingredientID  
from menu_has_ingredient_cost,bill_details_has_menu
where bill_details_has_menu.Menu_ItemID=menu_has_ingredient_cost.Menu_ItemID) 

RETURN Ingredient ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should

```
RETURN @Ingredient ;
```

Also it needs an

```
END;
```

**Suggestions** for other/alternative changes:

```
BEGIN
 DECLARE Ingredient BIGINT;

 select Ingredient_cost_ingredientID into Ingredient
 from 
    menu_has_ingredient_cost,
    bill_details_has_menu
 where 
    bill_details_has_menu.Menu_ItemID = 
     menu_has_ingredient_cost.Menu_ItemID;

 RETURN Ingredient;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Ravinder's corrections, I would also:

- Replace the joining in the `WHERE` with a `JOIN`
- Ditch the local variable - you can return a result directly
- Because the function returns a scalar `BIGINT`, you will need to ensure that the query never returns more than one value, e.g. by using an aggregate.
- You are also missing a semi-colon before the `RETURN`

```
CREATE FUNCTION `new_function`()
RETURNS BIGINT
BEGIN
  RETURN
    (SELECT SUM(Ingredient_cost_ingredientID)  
      FROM menu_has_ingredient_cost 
        INNER JOIN bill_details_has_menu
        ON bill_details_has_menu.Menu_ItemID
          =menu_has_ingredient_cost.Menu_ItemID);
END;
```

[Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d4fe6/3)